# Issue validating in all rows of a table

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a table which consist of around 50 rows and columns on a page. I want to fetch all rows from table and write a function to check if 2nd column of all words contains word 'Silver'. I tried below code but it is not working. Can someone please help where i am missing an i am not that great with Javascript promises. If match to string is found, i just want to increment a count and then return count at end.

```
  fetchValues(SearchString){
      var matchcount=0;
      var count = this.ContentTable.Rows.count();
      for (var i=0;i<count-1;i++) {
           return this.ContentTable.element(by.css('[id*="DXDataRow'+i+'"]'))
           .then((Row) =>{
                return this.ContentTable.Row.element(by.css('[id*="uxSetList_tccell'+i+'_1"]'))
                .then((Column)=>{
                        var CoinInfo = this.ContentTable.Row.Column.element(by.css('a')).getText();
                        if (CoinInfo.indexOf(SearchString)>=0)
                        {
                            matchcount =matchcount+1
                        }
                        return matchcount;
                });
           });                
      }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you're returning a value from inside your `for()` loop.  That guarantees your loop is only ever going to be run once, and you're only ever going to examine one row.  Is that what you want?  (no, really, I have no idea.)  Are you trying to create a lot of promises and combine their results into a single number?  You might want to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to combine the values of all promises you create, and return a value from that meta-promise:

```
var myPromises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  myPromises.push(this.ContentTable.element(by.css('[id*="DXDataRow'+i+'"]'))
    .then(/* ...blah blah blah ... */)
  );
}
// return a single value from this function containing data from all promises
return Promise.all(myPromises).then((promiseResultsArray) => {
    /* calculate match count */
});
```

second, I think your promises themselves are written incorrectly.  You're assuming that the value of `i` when your promise's callback is *run* is the same as the value of `i` when your promise's callback was *defined*.  Because of how promises work in JS, that's not actually the case.

What's happening is that your `for()` loop creates a bunch of promises and then, *at some undefined point in the future*, one of these promises gets resolved and the function you passed to its `.then()` method gets run.  This function knows about `i` - it's right there in the function body, after all! - but the value of `i` right now is equal to the value of `count - 1`.  We're in the future now, remember, and the `for()` loop has terminated, and the termination condition for your loop is when `i === count - 1`.  This will be the case for every single promise you create in this loop, because they *all* get executed after the loop terminates.

You can fix this in a bunch of ways.  Probably the cleanest is to declare a new variable, initialized to the current value of `i` and never ever changed, and refer to that inside your `.then()` callback:

```
var i = 0;
var myPromises = [];
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  var currentCount = i;
  myPromises.push(this.ContentTable.element(by.css('[id*="DXDataRow'+currentCount+'"]'))
    .then(/* ...blah blah blah ... */)
  );
}
// return a single value from this function containing data from all promises
return Promise.all(myPromises).then((promiseResultsArray) => {
    /* calculate match count */
});
```

if you want more information, there are plenty of SO questions about how to use promises.

Comment: Can you please check below code? I am not sure why for loop is not working here? If i return count value, it is giving me value as 50. If i replace count inside for loop with 50 then also it is giving me 50 correctly. Do i need to convert count to integer?
`        fetchssd(){
            var matchcount=0;
            var count = this.ContentTable.Rows.count();
        for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            matchcount = matchcount + 1;
        }
        return matchcount;
        } `